# How to access other model instance fields from to_python in a custom Django field implementation

Tags: django, custom-field-type

How can I access the model instance from a custom Django model field's `to_python` call?
When I overrode `pre_save`, for example, I had `model_instance` as one of the arguments. 
`to_python` only receives the value. 
How can I do something like:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    value = value_based_on_another_field_from_model()
    return value
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_python` is the wrong place to do whatever you're trying to do. You should merely be converting data (as returned by a database) to a python object. The model instance doesn't even exist at the time that `to_python` is called on your particular custom field instance, so you're definitely not going to have access to it. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The model field is a specialized DateTimeField that converts dates to UTC on save based on a user profile's timezone for the model. It works great and I wanted to convert *back* to the user's timezone on load...  I need access to the model's created_by field.

Comment: turns out I needed the value_from_object function. 
Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks Ozan for removing me from a wrong direction. Sometimes that what happens when you do work at 3am.  :o)